# Laravel Nova - How to turn off auto-pluralization of tables in Dashboard?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

When I create a table `about` and link it to `Nova`, in the dashboard it will be displayed as `abouts`. Is there a way to turn off `pluralization`?

Bonus question: Can `table names` in the dashboard be detached from their `table` and customized?

**Edit:**

@Drown's answer worked in so far that now the `table names` in the dashboard are shown correctly as `donate` but when I click on the `table name` I am getting this:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'stuttard_db.donates' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `donates` order by `donates`.`id` desc limit 26 offset 0) {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'stuttard_db.donates' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `donates` order by `donates`.`id` desc limit 26 offset 0) at C:\\Users\\Artur\\PhpstormProjects\\stuttard.de\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:703)
```

In addition the `url` is shown as `http://localhost:3000/nova/resources/donates`.

I updated the `table name` in my `Controller` already. I think this is the only place where I manually entered the `table name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `label()` and `singularLabel()` method to define the text that should be used instead

Link to the docs : https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/localization.html#resources

Comment: Thank you. Could you take a look at the **Edit section**?